# How to find the PATH of Maven, when maven is inbuilt with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using **Windows 7, JAVA 8, Eclipse 4.14.**
In this Maven is Inbuilt-ed,I've created a **Maven Project** as well as converted some of the Existing **Java Projects** into **Maven**, When i try to run the **TESTNG Scripts** through Maven using Maven Build command, Its building the Automation Project,according to my dependencies it downloaded the resources from the respective repository and storing into (**.m2**) folder. But inside the package,inside the TestNG class, the moment when i do right click for **RunAs** command its showing only Run in **TestNg** , Not in Maven.If i do right click on the Project,Then its showing all the Maven Commands.After searched in Google its asking to set the PATH for Maven in Environmental Variables but the thing is "**M2_HOME**" variable has stored in it,But not "**MAVEN_HOME**".For this which path we need to use and how to set it and how to check the **version of Maven** from **Command Prompt**?

Comment: 1. You probably do not want to run a single test with Maven. Maven does a whole build with all tests 2. The Maven inside Eclipse does not have a path you can point to.

Comment: Different resources are associated with different plugins in Eclipse: Maven projects with M2E, test classes with JUnit or TestNG.